# how many storm topologies can be deployed on single storm server?

Tags: apache-storm

Currently I am able to deploy 24 topologies, but after that Storm is running out of Workers. Can any one suggest how to increase the Workers on Storms?

Comment: man, please mention why u downvote. nobody is perfect here.

Answer (score 1):

The number of topologies which can be deployed to a cluster ultimately depends on how much cpu/ram is available and how much cpu/ram is required by your workers.

You can increase the number of `supervisor.slots.ports` to have more workers on a given machine. If you define 10 ports you could have 10 workers.

See also [Setting up a Storm cluster](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.1/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html).